# USB stick doesn't store data

Tags: usb, fat32

I have several live usb sticks. I decided to use them as ordinary flash drive. So I formatted  them to fat32 using gparted. The mount correctly, but when I created file or directory on usb drive, and then replug it, everything disappears. I've got this problem for both linux and windows.

Comment: Do you unmount it before you unplug it?

Comment: Oh, that was the solution. But other usb sticks works well with just unplugging

Comment: They only work because writing happened to have finished when you were unplugging them. *Never* unplug a storage medium (harddisk/stick) without unmounting first.

Comment: Now everythin works well. Even if I unplug

Answer (score 0):

You unplugged the drive without unmounting its partition.

Unmounting the partition would have allowed the OS to flush any pending writes to the disk.

It is likely that the partition will need to be run through `fsck` the next time you mount it as its state may be inconsistent.

*Always* unmount the mounted partition before unplugging the drive it's located on!